# How to get the iterminal echo immediately in pty4j

Tags: terminal

I can't get the terminal echo immediately, and I have to wait until I send the newline character, otherwise I can't know what the command I send to the outputstream.
How can I get something like [haha@localhost ~]$ (command) from the pty
immediately

I am working on a pty application, I send the command to the outputstream of the ptyprocess and get the result in the inputstream.

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(System.getenv());
env.put("TERM", "xterm");
String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-l" };
PtyProcess ptyProcess = new PtyProcessBuilder().setCommand(cmd).setEnvironment(env).start();
OutputStream outputStream = ptyProcess.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = ptyProcess.getInputStream();
```